# How to check cloudformation template used to create codepipeline

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to add new stage to codepipeline which is deployed through cloudformation template. I cant able to find the CloudFormation template used to create codepipeline since there are several templates in my account. Is there a way to know which CloudFormation template is used to create the codepipeline from list of templates in AWS Account.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check tags of your resources. CFN adds automatic tags,

Comment: @Marcin: Can you please explain in detail how to check that. I had pipeline named "Database-pipeline" which is deployed through CFN. I don't know which CFN is used to deploy the pipeline.

Comment: Go to the resource CF template created and check the tag. In your case select the pipeline cf template created check the tag for that resource.